# Relationship between the homology of two types of tensor products of $\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$-graded objects?

Tags: matrices, homological-algebra

Let's consider a $2$-periodic complex $F$ of free $R$-modules, which is just a $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$-graded complex
$$F_1 \xrightarrow{d_1} F_0 \xrightarrow{d_0} F_1$$
(really the arrow $d_0$ should be going backwards). The tensor product $F \otimes_R G$ of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$-graded complexes is given by
$$\begin{matrix} F_0 \otimes G_0 \\\ \oplus \\\ F_1 \otimes G_1 \end{matrix} \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \otimes d_0^F & d_1^F \otimes 1  \\\ d_0^F \otimes 1 & -1 \otimes d_1^G\end{pmatrix}} \begin{matrix} F_0 \otimes G_1 \\\ \oplus \\\ F_1 \otimes G_0 \end{matrix} \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \otimes d_1^G & d_1^F \otimes 1 \\\ d_0^F \otimes 1 & -1 \otimes  d_0^G  \end{pmatrix}} \begin{matrix} F_0 \otimes G_0 \\\ \oplus \\\ F_1 \otimes G_1 \end{matrix}$$
There are natural "unfolding" functors $\tau_i$ that send a $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$-graded complex to a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded complex, defined as follows:
$$\tau_i (F) = 0 \to \underbrace{F_1 \to F_0 \to F_1 \to \cdots \to F_1 \to F_0}_{i \ \text{times}} \to 0.$$
My question is, broadly stated, the following: what is the relationship between these unfolding functors and the tensor products in the category of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$-graded complexes (if any)? More precisely I can consider the following two complexes:
$$\tau_i (F) \otimes_R \tau_i (F) \quad (\mathbb{Z}\text{-graded tensor}) \quad \text{versus} \quad \tau_{i} (F \otimes_R F).$$
The first term of course has many more terms appearing in each homological degree compared to the latter, and I am interested in the difference in the homology of both of these tensor products. In my case I am really working over a finite dimensional $k$-algebra $R$, and $F$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ graded complex of $R$-modules, so both of the above complexes have homology that is a finite dimensional vector space, and it would be great if there were some inequality approximately of the form
$$i \cdot h (\tau_{i} (F \otimes F)) \leq h (\tau_i (F) \otimes \tau_i (F)),$$
where $h$ denotes the vector space dimension of all of the homology of a given complex (so add the dimensions of the homology in each degree). In other words, I would like that $\tau_i (F) \otimes \tau_i (F)$ also has much bigger homology than $\tau_{i} (F \otimes F)$; the thing that is counterintuitive here is that there seems to be no direct correspondence relating the cycles/boundaries of these two complexes, and yet experimentally there does seem to be an inequality of the above form (up to adding constants on either side that don't actually depend on $i$ as $i \to \infty$). One other thing (if it makes any difference) is that I only care about $i$ asymptotically, so maybe one should expect uniformity only after taking $i$ arbitrarily large.